# Objects in a category

Tags: category-theory

My friends and I are trying to structure the proof of this question but we are stump. Can anyone help us?

Prove that a final object in a category C is initial in the opposite category C(op).

Comment: @CameronBuie the question seems the same but they person that posted the question is being harshed by those members that responded to the post

Comment: But this question is presented identically and is not likely to be received any more warmly than the original.  There's no point in repeating the experiment, so the least you can do is edit your question to show more effort.  Write down anything you've tried no matter how flawed you're worried it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An object $X$ in the category $\mathcal C$ is final if for every object $Y$ in $\mathcal C$ there is a unique morphism $Y\to X$ in $\mathcal C$. The objects in the opposite category $\mathcal C^{\text{op}}$ are the objects in $\mathcal C$ and a morphism $Y\to Z$ in $\mathcal C^{\text{op}}$ is the same as a morphism $Z\to Y$ in $\mathcal C$. Therefore for every object $Y$ in $\mathcal C^{\text{op}}$ there is a unique morphism $X\to Y$ in $\mathcal C^{\text{op}}$. That is, $X$ is initial object in $\mathcal C^{\text{op}}$.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: what happens to all the arrows pointing to a final object in the opposite category?

Comment: An final object I is an object such that for every other object O in the category, there is a unique morphism O->I. Is this true?

Comment: This information is surely available in your text, notes, and all over the internet. Why are you asking me?! :)

Comment: I googled it and didnt find it. I am working on these problems for fun

Comment: I don't believe you. (That you couldn't find it.)

Comment: Prove me wrong lol. :)

Comment: Proof: Obvious. $\qed$ What do I win? :)

Comment: No. lol. You need evidence to state that it is trival